# twint library search returns variable count of tweets upon each time running the code, and the limit count is not respected

Tags: python

Below is the code i am using. Everytime the query runs, I get a different number of tweet counts

```
config1= twint.Config()
config1.Username = "dogecoin"
config1.Hide_output=True
config1.Store_csv = True
config1.Store_object = True
config1.limit=10
config1.Output = "dogecoin.csv"
twint.run.Search(config1)
df1= pd1.read_csv('dogecoin.csv')
print(df1['tweet'])
```